# Remove or relocate Java icon in Dock

Tags: macos, mojave, dock, java

I am using a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave with the latest version of Java.

When i run my Java program, it shows 2 icons in the Dock. Is it possible to remove 1 or relocate both?

I cannot use a 3rd party hide program, it won't move if I drag it off the Dock. Does anyone have any methods to relocate or hide the icons?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right click on the icon in the dock and select hide. This should hide one of the icons.  See image

[image]

Comment: it shows a hide option but it doesnt actually happen after i click it

Comment: That is to Show/Hide the app, not the icon itself. Wrong answer.